# GUI freezes after clicking restart button

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

My tic tac toe game works after the first round, but when the game is over and I clicked the restart button, the next round I suddenly can't click anything, everything freezes and the Player function thread keeps sleeping keeps going even after I clicked a button on the GUI (which is supposed to stop the while loop). The restart button's function is to reboot every variables for next round's use, and to redirect the flow of the game back to the Execute() function (controls the sequence of the game). Player function on my GUI waits for the player to make a move by having a thread on a while loop. I am wondering if the problem is on the relationship between the GUI action listeners of every button and the while loop on my Player function? Please help this is my code.

```
void Execute(){
    //Declaration
    //Initialization
    //Execution
    if(int_info == 0){
        this.int_turn = Object_GUI.setTurn(); //who makes the first turn?
    }//if
    while(bool_game == true){
        if(int_info == 1){
            Object_State.whoseTurn(this.int_turn); //the first turn player 
makes his move and checked if the move is not yet taken
        }//if
        if(int_info == 2){
            Object_GUI.placeMove(int_turn); //the move of the player will be 
placed on the GUI depending on its coordinates 
        }//if
        if(int_info == 3){
            Object_Rules.whoWins(); //Checks if theres a winner
        }//if
        if(int_info == 4){
            Object_State.nextTurn(int_turn); //sets the table for the next 
player
        }//if
        if(int_info == 5){
            reset(); //resets the variables for the next player
        }//if
    }//while(bool_game == true)
    //Return
}//void Execute()

void reset(){
    //Declaration
    //Initialization
    int_info = 1;
    //Execution
    Object_GUI.reset(); //Variables reset: String move
    Object_State.reset(); //Variables reset: String_move, playerDone
    Object_Algorithm.reset(); //Variables reset: String move
    Object_Log.reset(); //Variables reset: NONE
    //Return
}//void reset

void reboot(){
    //Declaration
    //Initialization
    int_turn = 0;
    int_info = 0;
    Object_GUI.reboot();
    Object_State.reboot();
    Object_Rules.reboot();
    Object_Algorithm.reboot();
    Object_Log.reboot();
    //Execution
    //Return
}//void reset()

void restart(){
    //Declaration
    //Initialization
    //Execution
     reboot();
     bool_game = true;
     Execute();
    //Return
}//void restart()
}//public class System_Manager
```

This is my GUI java file (same package) I'll just include the bits I think contributes to the problem.

```
void placeMove(int placeMove_currTurn){
    //Declaration
    //Initialization
    //Execution
    split = String_move.split(",");
    if(X == placeMove_currTurn){ //If the first turner is equal to the 
player on the current turn
        if(split[0].equals("0") && split[1].equals("0")){
            _00.setText("X");
        }//if
        else if(split[0].equals("0") && split[1].equals("1")){
            _01.setText("X");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("0") && split[1].equals("2")){
            _02.setText("X");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("1") && split[1].equals("0")){
            _10.setText("X");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("1") && split[1].equals("1")){
            _11.setText("X");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("1") && split[1].equals("2")){
            _12.setText("X");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("2") && split[1].equals("0")){
            _20.setText("X");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("2") && split[1].equals("1")){
            _21.setText("X");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("2") && split[1].equals("2")){
            _22.setText("X");
        }//else if
    }//if
    else{
        if(split[0].equals("0") && split[1].equals("0")){
            _00.setText("O");
        }//if
        else if(split[0].equals("0") && split[1].equals("1")){
            _01.setText("O");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("0") && split[1].equals("2")){
            _02.setText("O");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("1") && split[1].equals("0")){
            _10.setText("O");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("1") && split[1].equals("1")){
            _11.setText("O");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("1") && split[1].equals("2")){
            _12.setText("O");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("2") && split[1].equals("0")){
            _20.setText("O");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("2") && split[1].equals("1")){
            _21.setText("O");
        }//else if
        else if(split[0].equals("2") && split[1].equals("2")){
            _22.setText("O");
        }//else if
    }//else
    Object_System_Manager.getInfo(3);
    //Return
}//void placeMove()
```

A bit of my action listener..

```
  _00.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    System.out.println("0,0");
                    Object_State.State_String_move = "0,0";
                    Object_State.playerDone = true;
                }//void actionPerformed
   });
```

And the Player function

```
void Player(){
    //Declaration
    //Initialization
    //Execution
    System.out.println("Player's Turn");
    while(playerDone == false){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }//catch
    }//while
    //Return
}//void Player()
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code this does not look informative enough

Comment: 1) For better help sooner post a valid [mcve] please. 2) Follow Java naming conventions. 3) Learn what an MVC pattern is and try to apply it. 4) `Thread.sleep()` on a GUI based application doesn't seem like the best idea...